# No puedo obtener la fecha especifica en el formato que deseo CalendarView

Tags: android, android-studio, date

Estoy intentando obtener la fecha a través del método `onSelectedDayChage()` en un `fragment`, el problema es que cuando agrego el `pattern` me muestra que el año en que estoy es 3919 y si lo dejo sin `pattern` me obtiene la fecha correcta pero también la hora en el mismo campo, y solo quiero obtener la fecha. Acá el código. (estoy solo probando con el `pattern` `yyyy` pero necesito la fecha así `dd-MM-yyyy`)

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
                        String actualdate = sdf.format(new Date(year,month,dayOfMonth));
                        namedate.setText(actualdate);
                        calendarView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Allí intento solo obtener el año para probar y la salida es:

> 3919

Comment: y por que no solo obtienes el año de la vista? String.valueof(year)

Comment: Pensé que debía generar un formato nuevo con los valores que recibía de `onSelectedDayChange` quizás por eso mi error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas mostrar únicamente el año, convierte el valor obtenido del año a String y asignalo a tu TextView:

```
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                    String actualdate = String.valueOf(year);

                    namedate.setText(actualdate);
                    calendarView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                }
```

Si deseas mostrar la fecha completa, puedes concatenar los valores obtenidos en el método `onSelectedDayChange()`:

```
              @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                    String actualdate = year + "/"+ month + "/"+ day;

                    namedate.setText(actualdate);
                    calendarView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                }
```

---

Pero si deseas cambiar a otro formato entonces necesitas definir un formato inicial de acuerdo a los valores obtenidos y cambiarlo a un formato deseado, ejemplo:

```
   @Override
   public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        //Define formato inicial.             
        String fecha = (year + "/"+ month + "/"+ day);
        DateFormat formatoInicial = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

        String actualdate = "";
        try {
            Date dateInicial = formatoInicial.parse(fecha);
            //* Aqui define el formato deseado.
            String nuevoFormato = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

            SimpleDateFormat formatoSalida = new SimpleDateFormat(nuevoFormato);
            actualdate = formatoSalida.format(dateInicial);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


         namedate.setText(actualdate);
         calendarView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      }
   });
```

Esto obtendría el valor :

`30-Jan-2019`

Comment: Pero veo que solo quiere capturar el año, SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

Comment: ¿Será que solo desea el año? @IgmerRodriguez , veo que comenta desea "obtener la fecha" :-/ bueno, agregué esa opción en mi respuesta.

Comment: sii ya lo vi! saludos!

Comment: quiero la fecha con este `pattern` `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: Tal cual lo coloco en el ejemplo @Elenasys, probaré y aviso si me sirve de esa forma

Comment: @Elenasys me funciono el de "mostrar fecha completa", el segundo ejemplo, solo que `String actualdate = year + "/"+ (month+1) + "/"+ day;` agregue un +1 al mes ya que al seleccionar enero me mostraba mes `0` pero con eso quedo bien, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

yo utilizo un calendario en el que me permite escoger la fecha y mostrarlo no solo en un texto si no también en una imagen, acá te paso el código:

```
imagenGenerator= new ImageGenerator ( this.getActivity ());
imagenGenerator.setIconSize ( 50,50 );
imagenGenerator.setDateSize ( 30 );
imagenGenerator.setMonthSize ( 10 );

imagenGenerator.setDatePosition ( 42 );
imagenGenerator.setMonthPosition ( 14 );

imagenGenerator.setDateColor ( Color.parseColor ( "#3c6eaf" ) );
imagenGenerator.setMonthColor ( Color.WHITE );

imagenGenerator.setStorageToSDCard ( true );

FechaInv.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                calendario= Calendar.getInstance ();
                int year= calendario.get ( Calendar.YEAR );
                int month= calendario.get ( Calendar.MONTH);
                int day= calendario.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

                final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog ( getActivity () , new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener () {
                    @Override

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int SelectedYear, int SelectedMonth, int SelectedDay) {

                        FechaInv.setText (  SelectedDay+ "-"+SelectedMonth+"-"+ SelectedYear);

                        calendario.set ( SelectedYear, SelectedMonth, SelectedDay );
                        GeneraIcono= imagenGenerator.generateDateImage ( calendario, R.drawable.calendar );
                        DisplayImagen.setImageBitmap (GeneraIcono);

                    }
                }, year, month, day );
                mDatePicker.show ();
            }
        });

    }
} );
```

Nota: necesitas descargar una imagen de un calendario en blanco y ya :), espero y te sirva.